# Junit: @Parameters method is ran before any other test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junitparams

I have a regular parametrized test class, done with JUnit 4.12 (also tested 4.13.1).

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void myTest() ...

  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> data() { ...}

  public MyTest(...)
```

In the application, there is a design issue that I cannot fix (I mean not now because too much impact). There are some static attributes in other classes, e.g.

```
public class StaticClass {
  public static Map<String, String> staticMap = new HashMap<>();
```

`MyTest.data()` add some data to this `staticMap` (which is bad, but I have no choice). But some other tests also use this attribute, they add data and then clean it.

I noticed in debug mode that, when I run the tests (at least from intellij), it:

- call the `MyTest.data()` at the very beginning (which is strange): data is added to `staticMap`,
- it runs a bunch of tests, that will use and clean `staticMap`
- when it runs MyTest, then necessary data has been cleaned.

It looks like a strange behavior, I'd expect the @Parameters methods to be executed when the test class is initiated.

I also tested with `JUnitParamsRunner` (with a provider method and also a provider class) and I have the same behavior.

Is there any way to bypass this behavior?

Comment: "MyTest.data() add some data to this staticMap (which is bad, but I have no choice)" can you explain why you have no choice? Can't you do the mutation of `staticMap` in a `@Before` method?

Comment: Very good idea, thx, it works